# Side effect of volatile read/write of nullptr

Tags: c++, c++20

I was watching [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9N_wJ7oIHDk&t=0s&ab_channel=KonstantinVladimirov) c++ lection (it's in russian).
At around 16:10 the lector asked an open question:

Having this code:

```
int* foo()
{
    volatile auto a = nullptr;
    int* b = a;
    return b;
}

int main()
{}
```

Clang generates [the following](https://godbolt.org/z/EdjbdYhcM) assembly for `foo` (-Ofast)

```
    mov     qword ptr [rsp - 8], 0 # volatile auto a = nullptr;
    xor     eax, eax
    ret
```

Meaning the compiler assumes there is no side effect for reading from `a` and basically removes `int* b = a;` part of the code.

GCC on the other hand [generates](https://godbolt.org/z/e8TMMsn6K) a bit different code

```
    mov     QWORD PTR [rsp-8], 0 # volatile auto a = nullptr;
    mov     rax, QWORD PTR [rsp-8] # int* b = a;
    xor     eax, eax
    ret
```

Here compiler believes reading from `a` does produce the side effect and leaves everything as is.

The question is what is the correct behaviour according to C++20 standard?

Comment: Pretty sure this is going to fall under the as-if rule.  If the optimization has no observable effect,  it is allowed to be done.

Comment: @NathanOliver Access to `volatile`s is considered observable, although the detailed meaning of that is implementation-defined. (Of course the standard doesn't say anything about what particular instructions should be emitted.)

Comment: The C++ code (assuming it is well-formed) needs to conform to the behavior required of the C++ abstract machine.  There is plenty of latitude given to the compiler vendors to optimize the abstract machine behavior into the native code.  (Ill-formed code can result in all sorts of fun behavior.  Where "fun" is defined as having to go into work at 8pm on a Friday and work all weekend non-stop to debug the code and push a change out into production.)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The type of `a` will be `volatile std::nullptr_t`.

`std::nullptr_t` isn't really required to have any internal state, although it is specified to have the same size as `void*`. Only the conversion behavior is specified for this type.

There is no need for `std::nullptr_t` to store a value in the memory it occupies. All conversion behavior only depends on the fact that the source has `std::nullptr_t` type. So there doesn't need to be a `0` value written or read there. The assignment `int* b = a;` does not depend on any state or value stored in `a`, only on its type.

I would say both behaviors are correct. What exactly the meaning of the observable side effect of `volatile` access is is anyway implementation-defined and if `std::nullptr_t` is implemented to not actually use any of its memory to store value, then one wouldn't expect any instruction loading/storing from/to it to be generated for the initialization and the implicit conversion in `int* b = a;` anyway. But if `std::nullptr_t` is implemented similar to a pointer which always has value `0`, then it would be reasonable to expect a store and load.

Note: The answer originally claimed that `std::nullptr_t` could be implemented in any number of bytes of storage, which is wrong, as the standard requires `sizeof(std::nullptr_t) == sizeof(void*)`. See [[basic.fundamental]/14](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/basic.fundamental#14).

---

In fact after having a look at the standard, I think GCC's behavior is more dubious. At least according to [a note](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/expr#conv.lval-note-1) the lvalue-to-rvalue conversion on `a` is not supposed to access the `nullptr_t` glvalue. This would mean that there may not be any load from `a`'s memory location because it would introduce the possibility of a data race that shouldn't be presented by that rule.

Answer (score 0):

I've watched that lection too. I think that only gcc-approach is valid cause:

1. simple assignment need to change left operand object
   (https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/expr.ass#2)
2. lvalue to rvalue conversion don't do side-effect for nullptr_t
   (https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/conv#lval-3.1)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).